# Passing one StateObject class of one view to another StateObject class of a different view in SwiftUI

Tags: class, swiftui, view, observedobject

I have two views each with their own class. The first view has an @StateObject of class "DataClass" that initializes a simple struct DataStruct:

```
 struct View1 : View {
    @StateObject var dataToPass = DataClass()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: View2(data: dataToPass)){
                    Text("Navigation Link to View2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }

 struct dataStruct {
    var variable1 : String
    var variable2 : String
 }

 class DataClass : ObservableObject {
    var data : dataStruct
    init(){
        data = dataStruct(variable1: "1", variable2: "2")
    }
 }
```

I'm trying to keep this same instance of the DataClass/dataStruct and pass it on to View2 and its View2Class:

```
 struct View2: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var data : DataClass
    
    @StateObject var game = View2Class(data: data)
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
    }
 }

 class View2Class : ObservableObject {
    @ObservedObject var data : DataClass
    
    init(data : DataClass){
        self.data = data
    }
 }
```

I want it so that there is only ever one instance/initialization of dataStruct and thus dataClass and View2Class has access to it. View2Class must remain a StateObject. As of right now I am getting an error on the declaration of View2's StateObject: "Cannot use instance member 'data' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available."
I'm sure it is an easy conceptual fix that I am not understanding right now. Thank you!

Comment: Some observations:
 **do not use** `@ObservedObject var data: DataClass` in your `class View2Class: ObservableObject`.
 `@ObservedObject` is for use only in `Views`. In `View2`, you cannot use `data`
 to declare `game`, because `data` is not "available" before the `View2` is setup.
 That is the reason you get the error. Use
 for example, a `.onAppear {...}` to pass the `data` to your `game`.
 See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app
 for managing model data in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the error ("Cannot use instance member 'data'...") try something like this:

```
 struct View1 : View {
    @StateObject var dataToPass = DataClass()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: View2(data: dataToPass, game: View2Class(data: dataToPass))){
                    Text("Navigation Link to View2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }

 // ...

 struct View2: View {
    @ObservedObject var data: DataClass
    @StateObject var game: View2Class
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
    }
 }
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! DataClass was only initialized once and was passed to View2Class.

Comment: Also followed @workingdog support Ukraine advice and took out the ObservedObject declaration in View2Class, left it as var data : DataClass

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `data` to declare `game`, because `data` is not "available" before `View2` is setup. That is the reason you get the error.

Try this approach, using `@Published` in the ObservableObject classes,
and passing `DataStruct` from `DataClass` to your `View2Class` with a function in
`.onAppear {...}`:

```
struct DataStruct {
    var variable1: String
    var variable2: String
 }

class DataClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data = DataStruct(variable1: "1", variable2: "2")
}

struct View2: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataClass: DataClass
    @StateObject var game = View2Class()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .onAppear {
                game.setData(dataClass.data)
            }
    }
}

class View2Class: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: DataStruct?

    func setData(_ data: DataStruct){
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

Comment: I like where this is going, but I'm getting a nil value for the optional in the .onAppear. When I force unwrap (game.setData(dataClass.data!)) it gives a fatal error, and when I nil coalesce (game.setData(dataClass.data ?? DataStruct(variable1: " ", variable2: " ")) it gives the coalesce DataStruct.

Answer (score 1):

`@StateObject` is used to declare a source of truth with a lifetime automatically tied to a piece of UI on screen that requires reference type semantics (i.e. needs to perform async tasks other than simply holding data where `@State` would be more suitable). It doesn't make sense to pass data into one because then it is no longer a source of truth, because it then has a dependency - the problem is the object doesn't know when the data being passed in has changed (Which SwiftUI supports natively with its `View` struct and `body` func). I would suggest redesigning your data flow to be more SwiftUI compatible, there are some great WWDC data flow talks like [this one](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/).